# How can I replace the username and password using a shell script

Tags: shell, unix, sed, scripting

How can I update the shell script where I can replace username "u1"  to any value from user input in a .txt file

```
'username' => "u1"
```

Below is the existing code:-

```
#!bin/bash
echo "\nEnter Username to replace: "
read name

sed -i -e s/u1/"$name"/g /var/1.txt
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `sed`, we can split a statement into two - and replace the second part with the required variable [here, $name] - instead of hardcoding the script with `u1`.

`sed -i "s#\(.*'username' =>\)\( .*\)#\1 "\"$name\""#" /var/1.txt`

The same result can be achieved using `awk` as below:

`awk -v name="$name" '/username/{gsub($3,"\""name"\"")};1' /var/1.txt`

Comment: and if I need to add a comma at the end of $name, how can I handle this?

Example:- 
$name= admin
output:- admin,

Answer (score 0):

Try '$name' instead of "$name"

Best option is to use sed -i -r

```
 sed -i -r 's/u1/'$name'/g'  /var/1.txt
```

Another   option you can try is save this to temp file and move  it back

Example :

```
 sed 's/u1/'$name'/g' /var/1.txt > /tmp/temp

 mv /tmp/temp /var/1.txt
```

Comment: The option with -r worked great! many thanks.

in next iteration, I pass on input "u3" to be replaced by "u2" (from previous execution of above code, value "u2" is replaced by "u1"). how can this be handled?

Comment: I didn't understand your requirement completely . put sed in the loop . Also Please upvote my answer , if    you got the answer you looking for

Comment: I want to replace "u1" or any other value from input

Example:-

'username' => "u1"

Input value -> u2

o/p:- 'username' => "u2"

code re-execution:-

'username' => "u2"

Input value -> u3

o/p results:- 'username' => "u3"

Comment: can you put the sample content of /var/1.txt?

Comment: Never do `'s/x/'$y'/'` as that leaves `$y` unquoted and so open to shell interpretation. Also never do `cmd file > tmp; mv tmp file` as that will zap your original file if/when `cmd` files. The `-r` is adding no value. The safer way to write the above is `sed -i 's/u1/'"$name"'/g'  /var/1.txt` or `sed 's/u1/'"$name"'/g' /var/1.txt > /tmp/temp && mv /tmp/temp /var/1.txt` and be aware it will still fail if `$name` contains capture group reference (e.g. `&` or `\1`) or regexp delimiter (e.g. `/`) or some other characters. See http://stackoverflow.com/q/29613304/1745001.